# Hibernate: Index for ID of subclass java Entities that have one general table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to ask.
I have my super general entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class SuperEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private OffsetDateTime createDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "update_date")
    private OffsetDateTime updateDate;
}
```

And general entity that extedns from previous:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "base_entity",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"first_name", "last_name"}, name = "un_base_entity")})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "entity_type")
public class BaseEntity extends SuperEntity {

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

And then I have two more entities that extends from BaseEntity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "animal")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@DiscriminatorValue("animal")
public class AnimalEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "owner_name")
    private String ownerName;
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@DiscriminatorValue("person")
public class PersonEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;
}
```

So, I have 3 tables: *base_entity*, *animal* and *person*. Each of them has ID. IDs in animal and person are references on *base_entity* table.
Should I create index for IDs that are in *animal* and *person*?(I will have a lot of data in tables)

UPD: added liquibase scripts for this entities

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 11-1
      changes:
        - createTable:
            columns:
              - column:
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                  name: entity_type
                  type: VARCHAR(31)
              - column:
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                    primaryKey: true
                    primaryKeyName: base_entityPK
                  name: id
                  type: BIGINT
              - column:
                  name: first_name
                  type: VARCHAR(255)
              - column:
                  name: last_name
                  type: VARCHAR(255)
              - column:
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                  name: create_date
                  type: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
              - column:
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                  name: update_date
                  type: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
            tableName: base_entity
  - changeSet:
      id: 11-2
      changes:
        - createTable:
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: owner_name
                  type: VARCHAR(255)
               - column:
                   constraints:
                     nullable: false
                     primaryKey: true
                     primaryKeyName: animalPK
                   name: id
                   type: BIGINT
            tableName: animal
  - changeSet:
      id: 11-3
       changes:
         - createTable:
             columns:
               - column:
                   name: country
                   type: VARCHAR(255)
               - column:
                   constraints:
                     nullable: false
                     primaryKey: true
                     primaryKeyName: personPK
                   name: id
                   type: BIGINT
              tableName: person
  - changeSet:
      id: 11-4
      changes:
        - addUniqueConstraint:
            columnNames: first_name, last_name
            constraintName: un_base_entity
            tableName: base_entity
  - changeSet:
      id: 11-5
      changes:
        - addForeignKeyConstraint:
            baseColumnNames: id
            baseTableName: animal
            constraintName: FKgmpyb3wmodpc6y1qrp0jliykf
            deferrable: false
            initiallyDeferred: false
            referencedColumnNames: id
            referencedTableName: base_entity
            validate: true
  - changeSet:
      id: 11-6
      changes:
        - addForeignKeyConstraint:
            baseColumnNames: id
            baseTableName: person
            constraintName: FKgmpyb3wmodpc6y1qrp0jliyks
            deferrable: false
            initiallyDeferred: false
            referencedColumnNames: id
            referencedTableName: base_entity
            validate: true
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question about Hibernate - but rather about databases in general. So `create table` statements would be more helpful than JPA Entities.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev I use liquibase for create tables

Answer (score 0):

Indices help to speed up queries, so if you intend to search by one of the columns, it'd be wise to create an index. ID is a good candidate to be indexed:

1. We often request resources by IDs when building web apps/services
2. Those IDs are referenced by Foreign Keys and are frequently used when we join tables
3. Usually all IDs should have unique index anyway because it's a primary key

But indices take space and slow down DML (insert/delete/update statements), so do not add them blindly. You should understand which queries your app (Hibernate) generates and add only those indices that are actually used.

Relational DBs also provide commands to analyze queries and how they are going to be executed - those are called query plans. If you see that some of your queries are slow, you can use query plans to find the issues with the performance and determine which indices to add.

Comment: Yes, I'll have many requests for select by IDs, I have `AnimalRepository` and `PersonRepository` which extend from `JpaRepository`. So I'll cal method `findById`